# Automatic login to website, which is using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, php, python, asp.net, authentication

I'm need to automatically perform the login at: http://gsc.klub-modul.dk/. After I am logged in, I need to able to fetch pages from this domain, which requires me to be logged in. As far as I have gathered, the site is using ASP.NET to interact with the server. I am open to all suggestions. I'm looking for a script to do this, as I am still new to this.

Comment: I have updated my answer,check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is botting (Automated access of site or online game),so follow these steps,

### Generic steps

- Monitor the HTTP request being made by the browser (I use
  [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com),you might also find browser built-in network tool(press F12) handy)
- You need to look for cookies especially.
- In short you should be able to make same HTTPRequest on each event
  (by event I mean first time page request ,page submit for login and
  etc)

### Use python for botting

use these libraries [Mecanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) / [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) /[scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) / [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

### Tutorials to get started

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/
http://arunrocks.com/easy-practical-web-scraping-in-python/
https://classic.scraperwiki.com/docs/python/python_intro_tutorial/

### Stackoverflow links

[Scraping sites that require login with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121639/scraping-sites-that-require-login-with-python)
[Scrape a web page that requires they give you a session cookie first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754807/scrape-a-web-page-that-requires-they-give-you-a-session-cookie-first)
[Fake a cookie to scrape a site in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117491/fake-a-cookie-to-scrape-a-site-in-python)
[Python Scraping Web with Session Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890411/python-scraping-web-with-session-cookie)

### My Advice

I think if you haven't made a web scraper (web-bot or bot-tool) before than you should start with small things like fetching a specific information from a page which doesn't require login then move on to more complex scenarios

Answer (score 2):

As usual Asp.Net uses cookies for session, authorization needs. So basically you just need to make POST request to login page with Login, Password parameters, then you need to obtain cookies from response, and then make new requests for needed pages with these cookies.

By default these cookies are named ASP.NET_SessionId and ASPXAUTH

Comment: Once I've obtained these cookies, how to 'make new requests for needed pages'?

Comment: if you are asking how to make them on Python, then I don't know as I didn't use Python before. Or you are asking about different thing?

Comment: I'm asking how I make these requests for the needed pages, now that I have the cookies. I don't have to be in Python, PHP or javascript would do fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a similar problem but used a generic approach. I used [greasemonkey addon in firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to login on a game and save data on different db. Later I found out that I could've wrote a addon myself ([mozilla ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension))

Both of these technique will rely on javascript only.([example of a login script of fb in greasemonkey](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/57400))

The website was on asp.net too! You just need to receive the cookies and login from javascript code. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is another approach to parse data and login.